# macro is not resolved in make rule

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, fortran90

I have a make rule:

```
%.mod: %.f90
       $(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) $< -o $(@:.mod=.o)
       mv $(@:.mod=.o) obj
```

(and there are tabs before the commands, but I don't know how to make them appear here)

This works, but when I try to do it in one shot ...

```
%.mod: %.f90
       $(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) $< -o obj/$(@:.mod=.o)
```

make does not resolve the final macro.  It sends merely "obj/" to the compiler, which of course, can't handle it.  Can someone explain to me why, and how to re-write this rule more efficiently than I have done in my first version?

Also, what I am really doing is trying to get make to understand that some files depend on a .mod file, and that is the way to update a .mod file.  Anyone know how to do that, without going to something like makedepend or cmake?  Thanks!

Comment: 1) what do you expect `mv $(@:.mod=.o)` to do? Is this your actual makefile? 2) the "one shot" method works when I try it. What version of Make are you using? 3) Your second question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry, edited the question.  mv is supposed to mv the output to the obj directory.

Comment: I am using GNU make 3.81 on a 64-bit linux machine.  In the last part of my question, I mean that the FORTRAN90 creation of ".mod" files doesn't fit well with make's target/dependency structure, so is there a better way to handle it than what I am trying to do here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with FORTRAN90. Do you mean that it builds `foo.o` and `foo.mod` at the same time? And you have depndencies like `foo: foo.o foo.mod`, `bar: foo.o` and `baz: foo.mod`?

Comment: Yes, something very much like that.  FORTRAN90 build a ".mod" file, in addition to the .o file, if the source file describes a FORTRAN90 "module."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
%.mod %.o: %.f90
    $(FORTRAN) $(FFLAGS) $< -o obj/$*.o
```

When a pattern rule has more than one target pattern, Make understands that running the rule *once* will build *all* targets.